# What does nothing inherent mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does nothing inherent mean in this context? I looked up the definition for inherent and i still don't understand it[image]

Comment: **Blind** is misusing the word "inherent". What is intended is "nothing advantageous about controller aim assist, as it's worse [than something else]"

Comment: An inherent feature or attribute is *integral* to the thing. For example, if a medicine can lower cholesterol by virtue of its chemical composition, "ability to lower cholesterol" is one of its inherent benefits. But if the medicine simply gives the person energy to exercise, and it is the exercise that is lowering the cholesterol, "ability to lower cholesterol" would not be an inherent benefit of the medicine.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. It prevents searching and is problematic for people who use screen readers. Also please indicate the research you have done, e.g. what you found when you looked up "inherent" in a dictionary.

Comment: Images of text also have the problem that it's not a safe bet that they will be available in the future which would render this question completely dysfunctional if the image were to be removed.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to show what you found in dictionaries. The usages by the first and third person seem like they match the standard usage. The second user's comment is confusing, but I think rather than misusing the word they're just confused about the argument.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it the discussion is about MnK (= Mouse 'n' Keyboard) vs [external controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_controller).

Usually the point and click action is easier with mouse and keyboard, which makes "aiming" (point and click action in shooter games) easier. As a result of that controllers often come with aim assistance software to level the playing field. Though if MnK and controller players meet they apparently argue that the other is having an unfair advantage.

So Alex is making the point that a lot of talk is concerned with the aim assist software of the controller, but virtually no one is talking about the fact that MnK out of the box provide an unfair advantage over the controller.

[Inherent](https://www.etymonline.com/word/inherent) appears to mean "to adhere or to cling to" where herent "haerere" means soemthing like "to stick". So long story short it usually donates a defining or essential property of something.

So in that regard "inherent" refers to the abilities of the two options (MnK and controller).

The crucial problem is that Alex seems to consider the aim assist as an inherent thing to the controller experience while Blind considers the controller to just be the physical device and the aim assist to be something that was added later, so inherently the controller is disadvantaged and the aim assist provides a buff rather than seeing controllers as something that just comes with an aim assist to mitigate other short comings.

Comment: I believe this answer may be confusing the word "inherent" with "inherit," as "inherent" does not specifically have anything to do with passing down. M-W defines as "involved in the constitution or essential character of something : belonging by nature or habit"

Comment: @YonKuma Very good point I changed that part, hopefully that makes more sense :)

Comment: IMO it's not super useful to define words by their etymology, since there can be substantial semantic drift. Any reason to not just quote a reliable dictionary?

Comment: FWIW, ***inherent, adhere, coherent*** all share a common origin in Latin ***haerēre = stick, cling to.*** But the *meaning* of ***inherent*** is closely connected to "inherited [characteristics]", since an object's "inherent qualities" essentially means qualities which are "built-in" (from the beginning, by ***nature***, not ***nurture***).

Answer (score 0):

The controller is the physical device used to control the game.

Aim assist is part of the software of the game running on the console.

Therefore aim assist a property added on by something other than the thing in question, the opposite of an inherent property.